# Binding of a view variable to a UserControl ViewModel declared inside the view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am stuck in this problem since a few days, can't solve it :

I have some views `V1`, `V2`, ..., with view-models `V1vm`, `V2vm`,..., each using a `UserControl` `MyUC`, with view-model `MyUCvm`. UserControl `MyUC` depends on a `bool` attached property `myParam`. Let's say view `V1` defines the value through a CheckBox. I can bind `myParam` to the `CheckBox.IsChecked` in `V1` XAML :

```
<UserControl x:Class="V1" ...>
   ...
   <CheckBox x:Name="cb" />
   <MyUC local:MyUC.myParam="{Binding ElementName=cb, Path=IsChecked}" />
</UserControl>
```

In view-model `MyUCvm` I declare a property :

```
public class MyUCvm : ViewModelBase
{
   private bool _condition;
   public bool Condition
   {
       get { return condition; }
       set
       {
          _condition = value;
          Notify("Condition");
       }
   }
   ...
}
```

I want `Condition` to be bound to `myParam` so that what is displayed by `MyUC` in View `V1` depends on the checkbox `cb` (and other patterns for the other views).

Maybe I could code in `V1vm` an update of `MyUCvm` in C#. But I believe this is not the right way.

It seams to me that it is more "pure" to bind `myParam` in `MyUC` XAML to `Condition`, with some kind of (not working) code :

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUC" ...>
   ...
   <WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE? local:MyUC.myParam="{Binding Condition, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   ...
</UserControl>
```

Am I targeting the right solution ? 
How to acheive this ?

Comment: Why don't you bind the CheckBox to Condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually instead of twisting everything around, I have chosen to use simple ViewModel logic, which is much simpler.

In ViewModels `V1vm`and `V2vm` I define a property of type `MyUCvm` that I use to define the `DataContext` of the `<local:MyUC DataContext={Binding RefToMyUCvm} ... />` xaml element in views `V1`and `V2`.

In `V1vm`and `V2vm` I use a bool property `MyParam` to bind to the `CheckBox.IsChecked` (or something else ...). And I do the work in getter/setter of the property.

```
public class V1vm : ViewModelBase
{
  //...

  public MyUCvm RefToUCvm { get; set; }

  public bool MyParam
  {
     get { return MyUCvm?.MyParam ?? false; }
     set
     {
         if (MyUCvm != null)
         {
              MyUCvm.MyParam = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged("MyParam");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is much straitforward and simple...

Comment: Thanks to Sam and mm8 for helping me to find a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

When you need one custom control to bind to the properties of another control, you best solution is going to be to register dependency properties in the code behind of the custom control who has bound properties that need exposed.

You can certainly still get and set your viewModel bindable properties from within the get and set of your registered dependency property. However, that is going to be your best bet.

So make a DependencyProperty for your type of controller, give it a name, and register the onChanged if you care to monitor it in code. Then create your get and set properties for it to point the dependency property to.

From their, compile and reopen the xaml file that is trying to utilize it, and the property will now be there in auto-fill intellisense for you to bind to.

Happy Coding.